# Correcting a known bias in collected data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-mining, normalization, probability

Ok, so here is a problem analogous to my problem (I'll elaborate on the real problem below, but I think this analogy will be easier to understand).

I have a strange two-sided coin that only comes up heads (randomly) 1 in every 1,001 tosses (the remainder being tails).  In other words, for every 1,000 tails I see, there will be 1 heads.

I have a peculiar disease where I only notice 1 in every 1,000 tails I see, but I notice every heads, and so it appears to me that the rate of noticing a heads or tails is 0.5.  Of course, I'm aware of this disease and its effect so I can compensate for it.

Someone now gives me a new coin, and I noticed that the rate of noticing heads is now 0.6.  Given that my disease hasn't changed (I still only notice 1 in every 1,000 tails), how do I calculate the actual ratio of heads to tails that this new coin produces?

---

Ok, so what is the real problem?  Well, I have a bunch of data consisting of input, and outputs which are 1s and 0s.  I want to teach a supervised machine learning algorithm to predict the expected output (a float between 0 and 1) given an input.  The problem is that the 1s are very rare, and this screws up the internal math because it becomes very susceptible to rounding errors - even with high-precision floating point math.

So, I normalize the data by randomly omitting most of the 0 training samples so that it appears that there is a roughly equal ratio of 1s and 0s.  Of course, this means that now the machine learning algorithm's output is no-longer predicting a probability, ie. instead of predicting 0.001 as it should, it would now predict 0.5.

I need a way to convert the output of the machine learning algorithm back to a probability within the original training set.

**Author's Note (2015-10-07):** I later discovered that this technique is commonly known as "downsampling"

Comment: To be honest, your analogy confused me more than your actual problem ;-)

Comment: @David, apologies - but at least one of them made sense (I hope!) :-)

Comment: Yep, I get the point now;-) It might be possible to work around the rounding errors in your algorithm, rather than having to adjust the training input set... if you're willing to post some details of the machine learning algorithm (perhaps a simple code example) you could get some input on that.

Comment: I find the analogy clearer than the "real world" problem. Anyway, the accepted answer is perfectly right, but for future reference, it looks like you're doing what's known as Importance Sampling. [e.g. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling or google for a better explanation.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the following

```
calculatedRatio = heads / (heads + tails / 1000)
```

and you need

```
realRatio = heads / (heads + tails)
```

Solving both equations for tails yields the following equations.

```
tails = 1000 / calculatedRatio - 1000
tails = 1 / realRatio - 1
```

Combining both yields the following.

```
1000 / calculateRatio - 1000 = 1 / realRatio - 1
```

And finally solving for realRatio.

```
realRatio = 1 / (1000 / calculatedRatio - 999)
```

Seems to be correct. calculatedRatio 0.5 yields realRatio 1/1001, 0.6 yields 3 / 2003.